# Detecting and installing DLL files with CX_Freeze

Tags: python, dll, cx-freeze

CX_Freeze executables in Windows environments are dependent of some dinamic linked libraries such as `msvcr100.dll` which might or might not be present in the target computer.

So far my solution was to complement the CX_Freeze `.msi` installer with a `.bat` installer that will check if the DLL file was present in `%SystemRoot%\system32` and copy it there if not, but as far as I know this task can be handled by MSI files.

Another posibility might be to include the DLL file in the `'include_files'` option.  It seems to work but it will copy the DLL in the application directory regardless if it was already present or not.

Is there any way that the MSI file generated by CX_Freeze can check for this dependency and install the dinamic library in `%SystemRoot%\system32` when needed?